# Dutch dictionary in Evolution for Ubuntu

Tags: evolution, plugins, dictionary

I'd like to know how to install a Dutch dictionary in the mail program Evolution for Ubuntu.
In Preferences I can see which dictionaries (all English) are installed but not how to add another dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

The package you are looking for is called `aspell-nl`.

To install from a command line, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>), and enter the command:

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-nl
```

To install from Synaptic, follow these instructions (adapted from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Add%20a%20dictionary%20to%20Evolution)):

1. Open the Synaptic package manager and search for "aspell dutch". Check the box(Mark for installation) next to `aspell-nl` and click apply to install.
2. Restart Evolution.
3. Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Composer Preferences -> Spell
   Checking

   You should see the Dutch/Flemish language dictionary installed.
   Finally, open a new message and verify that the spell check works correctly.

Comment: actually it is hunspell, not aspell what does the trick

Comment: For anyone looking how to install Evolution spell-check dictionaries for other languages, use terminal autocomplete to figure out what package is there for your language, i.e. type `sudo apt install aspell-` in your terminal and hit `Tab` twice. This shows you the list of all the options. E.g. there is `aspell-sk` for Slovak dictionary, `aspell-cs` for Czech dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I've guessed and tried `aspell-nl` and it worked:

```
sudo apt-get install aspell-nl
```